# Convert Html with Base64 to email with cid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, base64

We have a tool that gives us html with embedded images as:

data:image/png;base64,1234

We want to have al images extracted and changed to cid images.

Is there a easy way to extract all embedded base64 images and convert them to attachments with cid: tags?

We use MailMessage for the mail message and SmtpClient to send the email.

The problem we have with the embedded images in base64 is that not all mail clients accept this method.

Comment: What are you going to be sending email with? If you are using MailMessage(), you'll probably want to extract the image from HTML into a Drawing.Image(). Attach the image to the email is not very straight forward but all the code is readily findable

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String() to get the bytes from the embedded HTML image

Comment: Thanks for your response I edited the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem? If so, could you share how you achieved this? Many thanks